# HD Native Thunderbolt Box sold separately?

Tags: pro-tools, avid, purchase-advice

I'm putting together a portable production sound mixing rig and I was looking at the possibility of using 192 I/Os with a laptop, and I can't find anywhere where they sell that little Avid HD Native Thunderbolt box shown here:

http://www.vintageking.com/Avid-Pro-Tools-HD-Native-Thunderbolt-Bundles?utm_source=North+Amercian+LIst&utm_campaign=c742265832-Avid_AAX_Video8_15_2012&utm_medium=email

All I need is that little box! Does anyone know where I can find it by itself without it being bundled with an HD I/O or some other package?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Out of topic, can i ask why did you choose a PT rig over a dedicated recorder? Do you see a big advantage of the recording capabilities or is it a matter of using what you already have?

Comment: A bit of both. I don't like the sound of the new HD I/Os and I've got a few 192s I can repurpose for a PSM rig. I just received an e-mail back from someone at DigiDesign (oops, I mean Avid) that they'll sell the box separately with Pro Tools 10 software for around $3500 but that's in the future.. Don't know how far into the future. 

Comment: @Filipe But I am getting a Black Box from JoeCo as a backup, though! The reason I am going with PT is that I sometimes need 24+ tracks because it will double as a live show recording rig. What sort of dedicated recorders other than something like a Sound Devices is worth looking at?

Comment: I'd live to try the JoeCo. I hear you on the 24 tracks.
For the type of work i do  i never used more than 12 tracks (even if its music)

The sound devices are the ones i'm more used to, used a Fusion 12 a couple of times and reeeally liked it to. Never touched a nagra digital recorder, unfortunately.

Comment: @Filipe Cool! I'll have to check those out.

Comment: @Utopia ever so slightly off topic... but dude, you're alive! :)

Comment: @Stavrosound ahh hey man! Yeah! I've been to some crazy places on gigs: Tel Aviv, Australia, Caribbean, to name a few. We've got to catch up!!!